# Ansible 2.3.0: Unable to evaluate date using to_datetime()

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I'm trying to capture a date in string format and parse it to an actual date in Ansible **2.3.0**.

Here's a snippet from my playbook:

```
vars:
  date_of_birth: "{{ bdate_YYYYMMDD }}|to_datetime('%Y%d%m')"

tasks:
- name: 2) Print date
  debug: msg="Birth date as discovered is {{ date_of_birth }}"
```

Command:

```
ansible-playbook ansible_playbook.yml -i inventory -k -v --extra-vars "bdate_YYYYMMDD=20181203"
```

This is the output:

```
TASK [2) Print date] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [****hostname****] => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "Birth date as discovered is 20181203|to_datetime('%Y%d%m')"
}
```

Looking to determine why the date doesn't get evaluated and stored in variable `date_of_birth`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use filters inside Jinja2 expressions (i.e., part opened with `{{` and closed with `}}`):

```
date_of_birth: "{{ bdate_YYYYMMDD | to_datetime('%Y%d%m') }}"
```

Otherwise they are interpreted just as string as in your example.